# how to give transparent border around an object in illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, borders

Hi I want to create a icon like this:

[image: Conference Image]

So the Middle person has kind of transparent border around itself.
So the other get cut automatically.

How to do this ?

Is there any way I can add transparent border ?

Comment: If it was photoshop, its easy but I am not an expert on illustrator

Comment: @KMSTR i tried knokout group but i did not know how to use that

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can create a knockout stroke by using [transparency to shape a knockout group](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/transparency-blending-modes.html#use_transparency_to_shape_a_knockout).

1. Put all three people together in a single layer
2. On the top-most person, add a stroke with thickness of your liking
3. From the *Transparency* pane, click *Knockout Group* twice and *Opacity & Mask Define Knockout Shape* once so that both have a checkmark
4. Set the opacity of your stroked person to 0%

Here's a demonstration:

[image: transparency knockout group demonstration on some meeple]